# Verify google developer identity card

Tags: google-developers-console

let me ask that when registering google developer, google will verify that the cmnd matches the email name instead of the master card when paying.
I paid $ 25 until the cmnd verification step was rejected, emailed to google also refused, no refund

i want to verify successfully`your text`